# exporting a video file in reverse order on iphone

Tags: iphone, video, avassetreader

I have been trying to export a video file in reverse order(play from end to start).
any idea how it can be done efficiently?

the best i could find is to create JPEGs files of the video frames (AVASSETREADER) and than to rewrite it in reverse order (AVASSETWRITER). but that is very slow.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Hi Amit,have you found any sample code on it.If yes, could you please help me. Code snippet if any will be really help full. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the only way to do it. I have code here if you want to try: https://github.com/mikaelhellqvist/ReverseClip

Comment: Hi Mikael,I tried your code but its not working on iOS 8 it seems. Do we need to change in code.If yes, can you please tell me what is the fix for it.Thanks in advance